# Does an object of a subclass also allocate an object of the parent class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, heap-memory, allocation

```
Class A
{
    int X {get;set;}
}
Class B : A
{
    int Y {get;set;}
}

B myB;
```

Say for the sake of argument that an object of type A is 4 bytes and an object of type B is 4 bytes.

B is allocated/initialized/constructed and its contents are stored on the heap.

Is the size of B 8 bytes with the pointers of both X and Y in tandem, or is it two objects of 4 bytes each?

Is it still resulting in two objects like the following situation?

```
Class A {}
Class B
{
    A myA;
}

B myB;
```

Can I presume, if these situations result in different data, that inheritance uses less heap allocation than construction due to the additional contained object having its data allocated -- and that the heap allocates this data outside its containing object?

Can I conclude that construction is much less memory efficient than inheritance?

**Clarification:**
When initializing an object of subclass type, are the bytes of that object's parent class's properties stored alongside the bytes of the subclass's properties? *Does B store a pointer to A or does it directly store the properties of A?* If it stores a pointer to an instance of A, that would make it the same in memory as if it had a property of type A instead.

**Addition:**
It was said that the data of B contains the data of A also in the first example. *Are there two allocations or one allocation when allocating the memory of a subclassed object?*

In the second example, you're allocating memory twice: once for the contained property object of type A and once again for the object class B, so I'm presuming that you have two distinct memory allocations and two distinct objects with a pointer to A inside B.

If a subclass only allocates memory once for the entire size of all its properties and all its inherited properties, and stores all that information inline, then wouldn't that make it a superior memory allocation approach than allocating multiple objects for one object?

Comment: what do you mean by "construction"?

Comment: What do you mean by *contains 1 byte of data*? Can you clarify? Objects do not contains any data unless you declare fields/properties inside them. Or you are referring on the space an object takes into the heap being empty (the overhead of an object)?

Comment: The memory used by an object is the sum of the memory used by its fields, including own fields and those of all ancestors. The implementation details are irrelevant and subject to change with different compilers, compiler versions, compiler settings, system architectures, and so on.

Comment: I didn't want to make up more distracting information to argue over, so I just said that, for argument's sake, each class, and by this I meant each object constructed using that class, contains 1 byte of data, so as to say that this is different from whatever the definition of the class itself takes up in memory, because in both situations, I am presuming you have two distinct class definitions taking up memory.

Comment: @Sparky If I were you, I'd redefine the classes as follows to avoid any ambiguity: `class A { int a; } class B : A { int b; }`. Doesn't matter if it's one byte or four, or whatever the size of `int` is if it isn't 4. Say it in code and nobody can argue about what you meant.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I added some properties.

Comment: @Sparky IMO fields would be more to the point. An int is an int. I don't know what an automatic property is, in memory. I guess there's a generated backing field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are running .NET on x86 architecture, an empty object has an overhead of 8 bytes (and a minimum size of 12 bytes). This means a `new object()` would occupy 12 bytes in memory.

Considering the following class structure:

```
public class Parent // overhead 8 bytes
{
    int a, b, c, d; // int 4 bytes * 4 = 16 bytes
}

public class Child : Parent // inherits everything
{ }

var parent = new Parent(); // 24 bytes
var child = new Child(); // 24 bytes [NOTE: this is a SINGLE object of type Child, not two objects Parent+Child]
```

They are objects of the same size because `Child` does not declare any other field.

The following class structure instead:

```
public class Composable // overhead 8 bytes
{
    int a, b, c, d; // int 4 bytes * 4 = 16 bytes
}

public class Composite // overhead 8 bytes
{
    Composable c = new Composable(); // 4 bytes (reference on the heap)
}

var composable = new Composable(); // 24 bytes
var composite = new Composite(); // 36 bytes (24 + 12) [NOTE: this creates TWO different objects, with one referencing the other]
```

Will suffer of a slightly higher overhead for two reasons: the "empty object" overhead of a new object created and the reference allocated for the inner object on the stack.

*Responding to your question:* Yes, composition requires a slight more amount of memory then inheritance, but the numbers are really too small to be afraid of.

#### Regarding your other questions

> When initializing an object of subclass type, are the bytes of that object's parent class's properties stored alongside the bytes of the subclass's properties?

Yes they are, as clearly shown by the inheritance example: we have a single object containing all the fields of both its class and any inherited class.

> It was said that the data of B contains the data of A also in the first example. Are there two allocations or one allocation when allocating the memory of a subclassed object?

One single allocation

> In the second example, you're allocating memory twice: once for the contained property object of type A and once again for the object class B, so I'm presuming that you have two distinct memory allocations and two distinct objects with a pointer to A inside B.

You are almost correct, the second allocation happens only if you **really** create that object. In your example you are just declaring a field `A myA`: this takes 4 bytes of memory (in x86) and no more. It will occupy more memory when you create that object (e.g. `A myA = new A()`)

> If a subclass only allocates memory once for the entire size of all its properties and all its inherited properties, and stores all that information inline, then wouldn't that make it a superior memory allocation approach than allocating multiple objects for one object?

Composition vs Inheritance have different characteristic, I do not believe it has any real-world impact but yes, inheritance occupies *slightly* less memory then Composition.

*Reference: [OF MEMORY AND STRINGS](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/) by C#... err... I mean Jon Skeet.*

Comment: I didn't add properties to the classes because I was implying any number of properties. I'm merely asking about the number of memory allocation operations on the heap in both situations, presumably given that they both contain the same kinds and amounts of data.

Comment: What is your doubt? The sizes calculated above clearly shows that there is no "double object allocation" in inheritance, while (of course) there is in composition.

Comment: My concerns about performance are in minimizing memory allocation operations on the heap. A property means a new memory allocation. So if I have 100 properties in an object, that's 100 distinct memory allocation operations with 100 pointers to bytes allocated on the heap. I don't want to multiply allocation operations through inheritance, but it seems the answer I'm getting here is that inheritance is simply an amendment to the definition of a class, as if you were to simply add more properties to it by hand, resulting in no actual additional objects being allocated.

Comment: Edited my answer and responded explicitly to your questions. I hope now this makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Can you clarify one thing for me: does a property in C# always mean a reference pointer is stored representing that property in the object's data, or does a property of a primitive type store its bytes directly in the object's data? I read this which was helpful: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/memory.html

Comment: A *property* in C# is really just a syntactic sugar for a pair of methods `Get` and `Set` (with exceptions on read-only/get-only and set-only properties). An *auto-property* is an automatically implemented property which `Gets` and `Sets` values to an "hidden" field. So anytime you are referring to a property you may do the same analogies that are done for fields. Value-type fields are always stored on the stack (this includes *references*, or pointers if you prefer, to other objects), while objects are stored on the heap.

Comment: Am I right in saying that primitive value-type fields have their data stored in the heap with the rest of the containing object's data? Any allocated object and its bytes would be stored on the heap while a reference or pointer to the bytes would be in the stack local to the context of its declaration.

Comment: [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/) may explain it better than me.

Answer (score 1):

> When initializing an object of subclass type, are the bytes of that object's parent class's properties stored alongside the bytes of the subclass's properties?

Yes, probably.  C# itself doesn't specify much (if anything; I'm not super familiar with the spec) about the memory model.  I'm fairly certain that's implementation-defined.  However, an instance of `Derived` containing a reference to an entirely independent instance of its `Base` doesn't make sense for a couple reasons:

If `Base` is abstract the memory model then not just allows for but actually requires the creation of an instance of an abstract class.

At the IL level managed pointers (the actual references) to `Derived` can be dropped in anywhere a managed pointer to `Base` is expected.  Now, we can rule out the runtime performing some kind of conversion (e.g. referencing that `Base` instance) because that would lose the RTTI.  But we know that we can cast that `Base` reference to a `Derived` instance at runtime, so it must not be modifying the pointer.

This would introduce a wrinkle when trying to access and modify fields of `Base` through an instance of `Derived`, however.  In that case the CLR would have to tack on field information to the instance v-table.  Certainly not impossible, but at that point CLR implementors would just be going out of their way to make things more difficult for themselves.  And as far as I can see there'd be no real benefit to doing things this way (unless you wanted to be able to change the inheritance hierarchy at runtime, which neither C# nor the CLR allow).

It would also incur a lot of rather pointless performance penalties by adding another layer of indirection that could have been avoided by just including the fields of `Base` directly in an instance of `Derived`.

Comment: Thank you for the insights; I surmised as much but didn't ponder. RTTI means Runtime Type Information. CLR means Common Language Runtime. IL means Intermediate Language. So many acronyms, so little time. ;P

Comment: IL is Intermediate Language, it's the language that C# compiles into and that the virtual machine executes (CLR being the virtual machine and "executes" meaning JIT compiles into machine code that actually gets executed).  RTTI is run-time type information.